# InetAddress.getByName works for unknown host

Tags: java, dns

I want to create a java program for reverse DNS check.

When i am using below code to get ip address for a hostname, it displays an ip address but there is no such host machine in my network. Recently i have removed that machine from the network.

```
InetAddress.getByName("deskmachin2558").getHostAddress()
```

Actually it should throws UnknownHostException but instead it displays an ip. Using the ip or host name, i cannot ping that machine.

How it works actually? Is there any cache stored in the server which returns the ip address for this machine.

Can anyone provide reverse DNS program in Java?

Thanks

Comment: need to cache clear of server from where route refers.

Comment: Created C# program for reverse DNS, it works fine. But in java, it fails for only that machine.